# "Too Broad" criteria puzzles

Tags: discussion, scope

This puzzle is closed because it is considered as "**Too Broad**"

[Create a star shaped crosswords](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51187/create-a-star-shaped-crosswords)

I thinks these puzzles, and all other <kbd>word-ladder</kbd> puzzles are also "**Too Broad**".
But why not closed as "**Too Broad**"

[Fruit Transformation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/50448/fruit-transformation) 
[Want to go from MANILA to UGANDA](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51181/want-to-go-from-manila-to-uganda)

So what kind of **Too Broad** puzzle is OK and what is not ?

Comment: I post the question, because the word-ladder puzzles is OK.

Answer (score 3):

The Word Ladder puzzle examples you provided are not considered too broad -
while there are certainly multiple solutions to a word ladder, the puzzle itself will generally specify a **win condition** - typically (and true of both the ones you mention), the *shortest path* - which permits evaluating the solutions given and definitively selecting one as the winner.  Often unstated is what happens in the case of a tie; the rule there is usually to accept the first solution of a given length, or sometimes, the first solution that does not rely on (say) proper names.

Your puzzle is completely open-ended. It just asks people to provide grids that work, and gives no indication as to what criteria will be used to select the "correct" answer.

Comment: I have edited the question, into open ended Challenge. Enjoy it !

Comment: Definitely agree with this. The Word Ladder puzzles are usually constrained in some way, and you can often find an optimal solution (be that shortest with pronouns, shortest without, or in one of those cases, shortest using only capitals or countries).

Answer (score 0):

The word ladder problems have an aim: to find the shortest solution. There are probably thousands of answers for each word ladder, but most of them won't even be thought of because they don't give a short solution.

For instance

> DARK -> LARD

You would probably think of DARK - LARK - LARD, and you wouldn't think of DARK - PARK - PERK - BERK - BARK - LARK - LARD. This is because you want the shortest path and there is obviously a shorter solution.

This aim makes the puzzle on-topic. There *are* tons of solutions, but they are obviously better ones. One answer will be better than another.

However for your puzzle, all answers will be exactly the same, no answer will be better.

This makes *all* those thousands of solution valid, and this is too broad.

You need some parameter or aim to make it not too broad, for instance:

> Find a grid that uses the least amount of different letters, with all different words.

This provides an aim, and a solution with 26 different letters isn't going to be as good as one which uses 5.

Comment: Hey! [Dard](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dard) is a word too!